# FancyBox responsive with HTML content

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I'm new on fancyBox 2.0 before I used [this one](http://fancybox.net/). I up to date my fancyBox version for the responsive feature but it didn't work in my use case... I do an Ajax request and I get the HTML coda that I want display in my fancyBox. 
That's what I do :

```
$.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    type:"post",
        data:{
            ...
        },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.error == 0) {
            $.fancybox.open(data.html,
            {
                type: 'html',
                afterLoad   : function() {
                    ...
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And the fancyBox displayed with this code are not responsive... So

Comment: What do you mean by 'not responsive'?

Comment: Resizing window resize the fancyBox

Comment: fancyBox has a property 'autoResize' which is on by default and should resize the content when the window resizes. You could try explicitly setting it, but the behaviour you describe should be out of the box (no pun intended!)

Comment: I tried to set autoResize to true but it doesn't work... what do you mean by out of the box?

Comment: I mean it's on by default, so you shouldn't need to change anything for it to work.